# iPad app: keyboard for editing UITextField does not always show

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a text field that is manually set to be the first responder.  There are times when this works fine, and others when it fails.

My application is a game with two methods of play: flashcard and regular.  The UITextField that is the source of trouble is hidden and not used in flashcard mode.  Once flashcard has loaded once, the keyboard ceases to appear.  If the player never switches to flashcard mode, the keyboard never fails.  The following is the code to make the keyboard show:

```
nameBar.hidden = FALSE;
self.animalName.hidden = FALSE;
self.animalName.enabled = YES;
[self.animalName becomeFirstResponder];
```

This is the code that switches modes:

```
playViewController = nil;
[playViewController release];

playViewController = [[PlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayView" bundle:nil];
playViewController.delegate = self;

[(vsl_mmp_crittersAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] playButtonPlaySound];   
playViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
playViewController.flashcardMode = TRUE;

[self presentModalViewController:playViewController animated:YES];
[(vsl_mmp_crittersAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] playPlayMusic];
```

I'm really confused about why the UITextField ceases to work after I switch modes, especially since I completely release and re-allocate the play controller to do so.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `becomeFirstResponder` from?

Calling it from `viewDidLoad` will give you the behavior you describe, and calling it from `viewDidAppear:` should show the keyboard each time the view appears.

Comment: It's called from an UIAlertView delegate function: `(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {`